# Audio Processing in recorded audio

Tags: iphone, audio

I am developing an application where i use AVAudioRecorder to record & AVAudioPlayer to play audio files.

But what i want to do is after recording the voice , do some speech processing and make it to cartoon voice & play the audio after that.

So is there any library or framework available by which i will convert my recorded audio to some cartoon voice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirac2 is one commercial iOS library for independent time pitch stretching, which is the effect that some apps use for the funny voices.

Added later:
Apple added the NewTimePitch Audio Unit, now built into iOS, circa 2012.

Comment: Hi hotpaw2, thanks for the information.Is any opensource alternative available for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the SoundTouch library as a starting point.  ( http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/ )  It's what I'm using in my application, and with the right settings it runs amazing in real time.  I would suggest taking a look at Audio Units for *at least* the playback part.  They aren't as hard as people make them seem.